# flask function missing 1 required positional argument while phased

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a button that redirect to specific link that user provided in his profile but when I'm clicking at button it keeps giving me an error

httml code

```
<form  action="{{ url_for('fb', link=random_user.fblink)}}" method="post">
            
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
              
                <div style="margin:10px;">{{ form.submit(value='Follow') }}</div>

        </form>
```

routes

```
@app.route("/match",methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def match():

users= User.query.all()
form=EmptyForm()
users_list =[]
for user in users:
    users_list.append(user)
    if user == current_user:
        users_list.remove(user)
random_user = random.choice(users_list)



return render_template('match.html', users = users, users_list=users_list, random_user=random_user,form=form)
@app.route("/fb",methods=['POST'])
def fb(link):
    return redirect(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get link value you need to add that to the route /fb/**link**

```
@app.route("/fb/<link>",methods=['POST'])
def fb(link):
    return redirect(link)
```

Comment: Thanks! It work but not quite as I wanted. Let's assume that this link is for example http://www.google.com. how to acces diffrent website?